# Finding a missing number in a series of inputs in python

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop, numbers

I am having trouble with this assignment. I cannot use advanced methods. My professor says this can be done only using loops. **No functions, no math class, NO lists, nothing.**

The user is to enter a number (n) greater than or equal to 1. Then, the code asks the user to enter as many numbers as n-1 and then the code is supposed to print out the missing number that the user didn't enter. So:

**Sample Run:**

Please enter n: 5

Please enter a number: 4

Please enter a number: 5

Please enter a number: 1

Please enter a number: 2

The missing number is: 3

-------------- This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. It only works if the numbers are entered in order.

```
n = int(input("Please enter n: "))

counter = 1
holder = -1

 while (counter < n):
     x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
     if x != counter:
          holder = counter
     counter += 1

print("This missing number is " + str(holder))
```

Comment: you need to store the numbers in a list then loop from 1 to n -1 checking which one is missing from that list

Comment: @E.Serra we are not allowed to use lists for this assignment

Comment: @Gary Wayne Interesting task. Can you put the black and white rules on what is not allowed? is a set an advanced method? Is a dict usable? "Dicts would be the easiest non list method imo"

Comment: @JasonChia No, only loops and the other basic fundamentals. He said the loop is the most advanced thing we can use. His words not mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formula:

1 + 2 + .. + n = n*(n+1)/2

```
n = 5

count = 1
total = (n*(n+1))/2
var = 0

while count < n:
    k= int(input('Give a number').rstrip())
    var += k
    count += 1

print('the missing number is {}'.format(total - var))
```

Answer (score 5):

If all the numbers you enter are distinct, then you can use the property of sum of n natural numbers.

If n = 5, then your total sum would be n*(n+1)/2, 15 in this case.
Then in the loop, you can calculate the sum of the entered numbers.

Subtracting this sum from the total sum will give you your missing number.

Comment: Do be wary if the case of n-1 inputs is not fixed. Also you should probably input some catch to avoid double inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
N = int(input('Enter n: '))
N_sum = N*(N+1)/2

temp_sum = 0

for i in range(0,N-1):
    temp = int(input('Number input: '))
    temp_sum = temp_sum + temp

print('Missing number: %d' %(N_sum-temp_sum))
```

Enter n: 5

Number input: 1

Number input: 3

Number input: 4

Number input: 2
Missing number: 5

Answer (score -1):

Something like, dont have time to finish it but this is what you need, the total sum of numbers entered should be x-1 + x-2 .... +1 then you add the numbers entered by the users and substract those 2, the result is the missing number

```
n = int(input("Please enter n: "))

counter = 1
total = 0


while (counter < (n-1)):
     x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
     total += x
     counter+=1

total_sum = 0
i =1
while i <x:
    total_sum += i 
    i+=1

print('missing {} '.format(total - total_sum))
```